# Learning Go -- Scope

Tags: go

Hi I am new to Go programing language.

I am learning from http://www.golang-book.com/

In chapter 4, under Exercises, there is a question on converting from Fahrenheit to Centigrade.

I coded up the answer as follows

```
    package main

import "fmt"

func main(){

    fmt.Println("Enter temperature in Farentheit ");

    var input float64

    fmt.Scanf("%f",&input)

    var outpu1 float64 = ( ( (input-32)* (5) ) /9)
    var outpu2 float64=  (input-32) * (5/9)
    var outpu3 float64= (input -32) * 5/9
    var outpu4 float64=  ( (input-32) * (5/9) ) 

    fmt.Println("the temperature in Centigrade is ",outpu1)
    fmt.Println("the temperature in Centigrade is ",outpu2)
    fmt.Println("the temperature in Centigrade is ",outpu3)
    fmt.Println("the temperature in Centigrade is ",outpu4) 
}
```

The output was as follows

```
sreeprasad:projectsInGo sreeprasad$ go run convertFarentheitToCentigrade.go 
Enter temperature in Farentheit 
12.234234
the temperature in Centigrade is  -10.980981111111111
the temperature in Centigrade is  -0
the temperature in Centigrade is  -10.980981111111111
the temperature in Centigrade is  -0
```

My question is with outpu2 and outpu4. The parenthesizes are correct but how or why does it print -0.

Could anyone please explain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite simply, the expression `(5/9)` is evaluated as `(int(5)/int(9))` which equals `0`. Try `(5./9)`

And to clarify why this is happening, it deals with the order in which the expression variable's types are determined.

I would guess that b/c `(5/9)` exists without regards to `input` in case 2 and 4 above, the compiler interprets them as `int` and simply replaces the expression with 0, at which point then the zero is considered dependent on input and thus takes on the type `float64` before final compilation.

Generally speaking, Go does not convert numeric types for you, so this is the only explanation that would make sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

The [Go language Spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types) indicates that `float32` and `float64` are signed floating numbers that follow IEEE-754 standard. Following text is quoted from [Wikipedia - Signed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero):

> The IEEE 754 standard for floating point arithmetic (presently used by most computers and programming languages that support floating point numbers) requires both +0 and −0. The zeroes can be considered as a variant of the extended real number line such that 1/−0 = −∞ and 1/+0 = +∞, division by zero is only undefined for ±0/±0 and ±∞/±∞.

Clearly, `input`, as a `float64`, when applied minus 32, turns into another `float64` which is negative. `5/9` evaluates into `0`. A negative `float64` timed by `0` is `-0`.

Interestingly, if you replace `input` with an integer, e.g. `1`, you'll get `0` instead of `-0`. It seems that in Go, floating numbers have both `+0` and `-0`, but integers don't.

**EDIT:** [PhiLho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15459/philho) explains in comment about the reason why floating numbers have such thing while integers don't: *normalized floating point numbers have special representations of +0, -0, NaN, +Infinity and -Infinity, while you cannot reserve some bit combinations of an integer number to have such meanings.*

Comment: Yes, normalized floating point numbers have special representations of +0, -0, NaN, +Infinity and -Infinity. You cannot reserve some bit combinations of an integer number to have such meanings...

Comment: +1 for answering the other interpretation of the question. I didn't even notice the negative sign :)

Comment: @dskinner Thanks! The negative sign got my attention because I didn't know the reason either. So I did some research :)